# ASP.NET Core API Docker: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: docker, api, asp.net-core

I cloned this [git repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/dotnet-core-api) and while it works locally, I receive a 404 error when I Dockerize the API:

[Local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gt2p4.png)

[Docker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PViWU.png)

[docker ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIgRA.png)

Below is the Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 5000
EXPOSE 8080
# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet build
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TodoApi.dll"]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: try to call only API from browser http://localhost:8080/api/todo and see if that works. if that works it means your publish command in dockerfile is not publishing the wwwroot folder correctly.

Comment: The API call was successful. Additionally, I can navigate to http://localhost:8080/swagger/index.html without issue. What should I add to the publish command? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open your app.js from wwwroot/app/scripts/app.js

it is problem case sensitive in linux environment.

and modify like this.

```
  $routeProvider.when("/Home", {
    controller: "todoListCtrl",
    templateUrl: "/app/views/TodoList.html",
}).otherwise({ redirectTo: "/Home" });
```

Solution also provided as part of the issue
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/dotnet-core-api/issues/1

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe it was that simple.

Comment: a useful tip, in future if you try such github example, always search for issues tab in github only for that repo and you can also raise issues directly there.